# Problems to use pandas within Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio

I have installed pandas then tried to import pandas
**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
print("Test Pandas")
```

**Error Type:**

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

No module named 'pandas'
```

I already have Python, Pip and Pandas installed, but when I am trying to use the pandas within Visual Studio Code the error bellow appears.

Someone could help me, please?

Comment: You can check that current environment of VSC (you can see this at left-bottom corner) is matched with the environment you installed python and pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try entering the terminal in VS code (CTRL + ~) and enter a python environment (type python and then hit enter). From there try the command:

```
help("modules")
```

That will show you packages installed in your current project environment. If you don't see pandas, it's due to difference in environment and just need to pip install pandas again from inside the project env.

**Side note**: one thing that can help to avoid this kind of problem for you in the future is using [virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)