# install and import pandas in vscode

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am a very beginner for vscode and python and computer stuff in general.

I am having trouble importing pandas into vs code, and none of the previous posts was helpful for me since I literally can't understand it and can't follow their steps.

I am gonna show you what I have done so far.

First, I open the vscode and open terminal (powershell)

Second, I type `pip3 install pandas` and it successfully install pandas
For example, I ran that command again, it gave me "Requirement already satisfied"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3xwX.jpg)

Third, as it seemed pandas is installed correctly, I type `py` to open python in the terminal and type `import pandas as pd`

But, it gave me :
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnS7C.jpg)

I really don't know why it is happening and what to do to fix this.

I will appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share the output of `which py` and `where py` also? You can put these commands in powershell and check if pandas is installed at the correct location.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478365/problems-to-use-pandas-within-visual-studio-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Make sure you are using the same interpreter as the one you installed the `pandas` library with.

Run the following code to print out the python interpreter you are currently using

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

[image]

Copy the full path of the interpreter and install the `pandas` library for it using the command

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install pandas
```

*Modify the above path to the path you just got*

It can also be done in the interactive window of the terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- try `pip` install pandas instead of `pip3`
- use `cmd` or `git bush` instead of powershell
- use virtual environments in the current working directory:

1. open vscode on new folder
2. Terminal > New Terminal: (make shure it's cmd not Powershell)
3. `pip install pipenv` (on cmd)
4. `pipenv install pandas`
5. close vs code, open it again on the same folder
6. Terminal > New Terminal (cmd)
7. `pipenv shell`
8. `py`